# Make package field referred in formula editor encryptable

Tags: managed-package, shield-encryption

We are working on making a managed package Salesforce Shield compatible. In one of the package object, we have a formula field which uses another package field and compare it with a string using CASE expression. If the subscriber tries to encrypt the referenced package field, Salesforce would not allow as it used in an unsupported way in the formula as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5)

In order to overcome this, we are thinking of using Workflow rules to solve it. To test the behavior, we created a sample package and packaged a workflow which updates a field using a similar formula(as in the actual formula field in the original package) in the field update action's formula editor.

Tested the sample package and it works fine without an issue which is contrary to the statement given in the Section (Field Update Actions and Custom Fields) over here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&type=5) which says:

> You can use field updates on encrypted custom fields, but if you try
>   to use a formula to set the new value, the encrypted field isn't
>   available in the formula editor.